# Workflow rule on opportunity to check account status (custom field) and update opportunity field status

Tags: workflow, field-update

I have created a workflow rule for Opportunity object type which checks if Account Production status (custom field) is set to "Cancelled" it will trigger an update field which would change opportunity stage to "Closed".  I have the criteria evaluation set to when its created and every time it's edited.
The opportunities (2- 1 per location) are auto created when the account is created. I tried testing this workflow rule, but its not working.  Can anyone help?

I have attached the screen shot below: 
http://speedy.sh/t92C3/cancel-workflow.PNG
http://speedy.sh/PAeYD/field-update.PNG

Comment: You would need to include your workflow rule as well as whatever you are using to create the opportunities code (trigger likely, or flow).

Comment: Is the account status a formula field?

Comment: @greenstork Can you please elaborate on this.

Comment: @JennyB No the Account status is a criteria so when Account: Status = 'Cancelled'

Comment: Edit your question to put all of your code up here for us to see, along with all of the details about your WF rule criteria.

Comment: Like greenstork suggests, can you add the code that is generating the opportunity record as well as a screen shot of your workflow criteria, and hate to ask but it's happened to me before, did you remember to activate the workflow rule?

Comment: @JennyB screenshots are above. and yes the workflow rule is activated.

Comment: When you manually create an opportunity on an existing account that meets the criteria, does the workflow rule work?

Comment: Nope it does not.

Comment: Can you try changing the workflow Evaluation Criteria to Evaluate the rule when a record is created, and every time it’s edited.

Comment: Are you sure that your account record has record type 'Production'?

Answer (score 1):

step1:- Make the status field on Account of picklist type which has value cancelled or any other
step2:-In workflow set rule criteria as ISPICKVAL(Account.Status__c , "Cancelled")
[image]
step3:-set the stage field as close lost in field update
[image]

Regards

Ajay

Answer (score 0):

Likely your account record does not have record type 'Production'.

Answer (score 0):

Please check record type of opportunity record and also make sure that your workflow is active and there is no other trigger which is changing status.